# Differential equation with Bessel function-like solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$$
r^2f''(r)+2rf'(r)-2f(r)=0
$$

I think a solution has something to do with Bessel functions but I can't figure out how. Could somebody help me to find a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Cauchy-Euler equation. I think [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Euler_equation) explains quite well how to attack it.

Comment: Many thanks, this wikipedia-page is very clear!

Comment: You are welcome,let me know otherwise.